# Is this construction of the "edge polytope" known?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, terminology, polytopes, convex-hulls

Given a convex polytope $P\subseteq\Bbb R^d$. I am going to construct a new polytope from its edges (I call it the *edge polytope*) with the following steps:

1. Take the 1-skeleton of $P$.
2. Extract the different edge directions $v_1,...,v_n\in\Bbb R^d$ from the skeleton. The edge directions should be normalized, i.e. $\|v_i\|=1$.
3. Take the convex hull $P_e$ of the points $\pm v_i$. Then $P_e$ is the *edge polytope* of $P$.

[image]

> **Question:** Is this construction known in the literature? If yes, what is its name and where to read about it?

On top of that, I am interested in applying the same construction to *embedded graphs*.

---

**Example.** Here are some polytopes together with their edge polytope:

- Regular polygons give regular polygons again, where a $2n$-gon gives the same $2n$-gone again (maybe rotated), and $(2n+1)$-gons give $(4n+2)$-gons.
- The cube (and hypercube of any dimension) gives the octahedron (or cross-polytope of the respective dimension).
- Tetrahedron, octahedron and [cuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron) all give the cuboctahedron.
- Icosahedron, dodecahedron and [icosidodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosidodecahedron) all give the icosidodecahedron.
- Prisms give [bi-pyramids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipyramid).

It seems that the edge polytope will have the same symmetries as the original (or more, if the original was not centrally symmetric with all vertices on a sphere).

Further, it seems that iterating this construction ends in fixed points, e.g. $2n$-gons, the cuboctahedron or icosidodecahedron. I have not found yet any polytope where the construction loops.

Comment: would your number 2) be truely needed within your construction device? or would it just suffice to shift all edges of a polytope in an individually parallel way such that its midpoint each becomes aligned at the origin? (and then applying the convex hull onto that)  E.g. a shallower triangular pyramid thus would result in an axially squashed cuboctahedron.

Comment: @Dr.RichardKlitzing This would be a different construction from what I have in mind. I need all the edges to be expressed as vertices of the convex hull. This is not guaranteed if not all of them are scaled to unit length. But it is not less interesting to do it your way.